# replace fragment with another fragment along with remove view

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have one activity and two Fragments. FragmentA and FragmentB.

I need to implement like, Initially  FragmentA should be there. 
and After `Button` click FragmentB should be there.

in my condition when activity is being displayed,fragmentA is showing and when click to button,fragmentB placed at the bottom of fragmentA and do not replace FragmentA

My activity Code is:

```
public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FrameLayout activityFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    activityFragment = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activityFragment);
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentA();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.activityFragment, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void goToFrag(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentRoot, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

my first fragment code:

```
  public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);
    return view;
}
}
```

my second fragment code:

```
   public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
public FragmentB() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container,false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should always have a `FrameLayout` in xml to replace your fragments there, then you use **different** containers to add fragments `activityFragment` and `fragmentRoot` .You should replace fragments in one container. You can use either `add` or `replace` for `FragmentManager` , so it `activityFragment` is your container (which should be a framelayout as a wrapper as the docs suggest) you use

```
public void goToFrag(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
    transaction.replace(R.id.activityFragment, fragment); // use the same container where you switch A and B
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: and the just use goToFrag onClick with the button in your FragmentA